# Is it possible to have google leaderboard working without having the play-services app on the phone?

Tags: android, google-play-services, andengine

I have an andengine game project where I am using Google leaderboard. Previously I was using Eclipse and older version Google-play-services. Now I have migrated to Android studio and using the latest version of play-services. But whenever i run the app on different different devices these are the results I get...

> Case 1) If the device doesn't have the game-play-services app
>
> App won't run unless you have play-services installed (get
>   play-services option)
>
> Case 2) If the device have older version of play-services
>
> App won't run unless you update the play-services (update
>   play-services option)

So my app totally become dependent on play-sevices app which I definitely don't like and many of my users hate it. Is there a way to basically integrate Google leaderboard without having these strings attached?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't use a service provided by play services without play services.

Comment: Who says you need to require the users to log in? You could just make it optional.

Answer (score -1):

No. Google Play Services allows your app to connect to given Google APIs (incl. leaderboard). Officially, there's no other access on Android than thru Google Play Services.

Comment: And by that you mean the play-services app and not just the sdk, right?

Comment: Play Services SDK contains code/libs that bridges your app to Google APIs **thru Play Services app**.

Comment: Okay, but it was possible in older version of sdks. So is it possible to use the older sdk in studio now?

Comment: You can specify exact version in gradle file `compile` dependency. So if you know which one worked for you, you should be able to build against  that version